# Apply UITextField restrictions to locally saved UITextField text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

We have a live application with certain amount of users. 
In the upcoming update we need to add name and surname input restrictions (to be less than 25 characters and have no spaces, numbers, etc.)

Here is how I do it:

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == surnameTextField, textField == nameTextField {
        let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
        guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }
        let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.letters
        let finalCaracterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: updatedText)
        return updatedText.count <= 25 && allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: finalCaracterSet)
    }
    return true
}
```

Everyrhing works as expected, except one thing. 
What if we already have users, which have numbers or symbols in their names/surnames? (The user data is stored locally)? They won't be able to change their name/surname.

How to enable existing users edit their credentials after this update?

For example, in case of Emma_Lew name the above code will always return false, as the `allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: finalCaracterSet)` is false (contains underscore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add the whole text in final character set, you can just add the new string and you can get the desired result.

Replace your code with below code

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   if textField == surnameTextField, textField == nameTextField {
        let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
        guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }
        let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.letters
        let finalCaracterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        return updatedText.count <= 25 && allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: finalCaracterSet)
    }
    return true
}
```